# WebAuthenticator always skip login page, How to get new login form for new user?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.essentials

WebAuthenticator always skip login page, How to get new login every time for a new user.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a sign out method. We go through all the available accounts that MSAL has locally cached for us and sign them out. We also clear the access token that we stored in secure storage when we signed in.

```
public async Task<bool> SignOutAsync()
{
try
{
    var accounts = await _pca.GetAccountsAsync();

    // Go through all accounts and remove them.
    while (accounts.Any())
    {
        await _pca.RemoveAsync(accounts.FirstOrDefault());
        accounts = await _pca.GetAccountsAsync(); //The _pca is the PublicClientApplicationBuilder
    }

    // Clear our access token from secure storage.
    SecureStorage.Remove("AccessToken");

    return true;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    return false;
}
}
```

**Update:** Sign-in

```
      public async Task<bool> SignInAsync()
 {
try
{
    var accounts = await _pca.GetAccountsAsync();
    var firstAccount = accounts.FirstOrDefault();
    var authResult = await _pca.AcquireTokenSilent(Scopes, firstAccount).ExecuteAsync();

    // Store the access token securely for later use.
    await SecureStorage.SetAsync("AccessToken", authResult?.AccessToken);

    return true;
}
catch (MsalUiRequiredException)
{
    try
    {
        // This means we need to login again through the MSAL window.
        var authResult = await _pca.AcquireTokenInteractive(Scopes)
                                    .WithParentActivityOrWindow(ParentWindow)
                                    .ExecuteAsync();

        // Store the access token securely for later use.
        await SecureStorage.SetAsync("AccessToken", authResult?.AccessToken);

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex2)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex2.ToString());
        return false;
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: I have implemented SecureStorage.Remove("AccessToken") after successful google authentication. Still it is picking email by default abd not asking for email second time. SecureStorage.Remove("AccessToken") not working basically.

Comment: Normally, MSAL already caches your authorization and can log you in silently if it’s still valid. But, if our authorization is not cached anymore, the user is presented with a sign-in dialog to complete the process. Please check mu updates for the sign method.